# How to refer an existing stack output variable value in my cdk stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I need to get the cloudformation stack, (which is already existing), Output variable value in my current cdk stack, how should I get that?

I tried using core.Fn.get_att?, but no much luck, can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the the output has been exported by the other stack, in CDK there is [Fn.importValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_core.Fn.html) for importing the output:

> The intrinsic function Fn::ImportValue returns the value of an output **exported by another stack**.

Comment: This is returning me a token? ${Token[TOKEN.9]}, it's not resolving while deploying, I'm using python, core.Fn.import_value('out_var')